# WCF Server Configuration for Windows Authentication for wsHttpBinding

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-authentication, wshttpbinding

I have to implement "Windows Authentication" on a service hosted on Server.
I am using "wsHttpBinding". In it "Message" is the default security mode.
Below are my server configuration:

**web.config**

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />

    <services>
          <service name="WCFWsHttpBindingHttps.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="WCFWsHttpBindingHttps.Service1Behavior">
            <!-- Service Endpoints -->
            <endpoint address="" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="WCFWsHttpBindingHttps.IService1">
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
          </service>
        </services>
    <behaviors>
          <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WCFWsHttpBindingHttps.Service1Behavior">
              <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
              <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
          </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
```

Below is my IIS configuration:
[image]

Inspite of all the configuration I am unable to access my service.
can anyone notify where I am making mistake or have I missed any configuration.

I am receiving below error when I am trying to access my service.
[image]

Comment: You should define a binding with security mode `TransportCredentialOnly` and `<transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />`

Comment: @Aria In wsHttpBinding  we don't have "TransportCredentialOnly". I need to achieve Windows authentication using "wsHttpBinding" and security mode as "Message".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `wsHttpBinding`, the security mode must be `Transport` for Windows Authentication on IIS to be used, in the other side consumers needs to have a server certificate configured.

If you use another security mode you will crossed with below exception:

> Security settings for this service require 'Anonymous' Authentication but it is not enabled for the IIS application that hosts this service.

so you have to `wsHttpBinding` as below:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Windows"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

If you use `Message` security mode, it means that you will be sending an encrypted message over a non-secure transport and to encrypt the message you will have to use your own a certificate, in the other side you also have to configure how the client validates the certificate, this ensure the consumers are negotiating to the right service.

Comment: Can you kindly assist in ws2007FederationHttpBinding for below question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53476104/wcf-server-configuration-for-ws2007federationhttpbinding-and-windows-authenticat