# WCF Server Configuration for ws2007FederationHttpBinding and Windows Authentication

Tags: wcf, iis, windows-authentication, adfs, wsfederationhttpbinding

I have to implement "Windows Authentication" on a service hosted on Server. 
I am using "ws2007FederationHttpBinding".
I am using "ws2007FederationHttpBinding" binding since I am receiving token from my ADFS server.

Below are my server configuration:

**web.config**

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />

            <ws2007FederationHttpBinding>   
              <binding name="SamlTokenCustomStsBindingConfig">
                <security mode="Message">
                  <message establishSecurityContext="false">
                  </message>
                </security>
              </binding>
           </ws2007FederationHttpBinding>

   <service name="XXX.Server" behaviorConfiguration="ClaimsAwareServiceBehavior">
        <endpoint address="http://serverurl/ServerServices.svc" binding="ws2007FederationHttpBinding" 
                  contract="ServerInterfaces.IServer"  bindingConfiguration="SamlTokenCustomStsBindingConfig"  />

        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>

 <behavior name="ClaimsAwareServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
```

Below is my IIS configuration: 
[image]

Inspite of all the configuration I am unable to access my service. can anyone notify where I am making mistake or have I missed any configuration.

I am receiving below error when I am trying to access my service.
[image]

As per error we don't have "Transport" or "TransportCredentialOnly" in "ws2007FederationHttpBinding".
So I am unable to move further.

Comment: Why you want use `ws2007FederationHttpBinding` just because of `WindowsAuthenticate`?

Comment: I have to implement windows authentication using ADFS so I am using "ws2007FederationHttpBinding". Is there any other option.

Answer (score 0):

You should comment this below line of code to avoid that mentioned error in your question:

```
<endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
```

but for implementing ADFS for WCF service needs several preconditions that can't be posted as answer but just for `Windows` authenticate mode this is easier to use `basicHttpBinding` by little steps.

so for ADFS implementation please take a look at:

1- [ADFS in Identity Solutions - Using Active Directory Federation Services 2.0 in Identity Solutions.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee335705.aspx)

2- [Federated Security: How to setup and call a WCF service secured by ADFS 2.0](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mcsuksoldev/2011/08/17/federated-security-how-to-setup-and-call-a-wcf-service-secured-by-adfs-2-0/)

3- [ADFS to secure WCF and Workflow Services hosted in Windows Server AppFabric.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appfabriccat/2010/12/14/ad-fs-2-0-to-secure-wcf-and-workflow-services-hosted-in-windows-server-appfabric/)

Comment: I have completed with ADFS configuration and I am able to receive token from server. But when I try to consume the service in "UserNameMixed" mode it is working fine but when I try for Windows authentication it fails.

Comment: Please remove `name="SamlTokenCustomStsBindingConfig"` from binding and `bindingConfiguration="SamlTokenCustomStsBindingConfig"` from service and try it again, because the same exception [occurred here](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/rfennell/2013/11/13/fixing-a-wcf-authentication-schemes-configured-on-the-host-integratedwindowsauthentication-do-not-allow-those-configured-on-the-binding-basichttpbinding-anonymous-error/)  as yours.